# Cluster analysis of large, multiple answer dataset

Tags: clustering, large-data, similarities, hierarchical-clustering

I have to analyse data from a marketing study. I will use SPSS. The questionnaire will look like this:

> Q: Imagine Situation X. Select 1-3 Criteria from the list that best describe your feeling.
>
> - C1
> - C2
> - C3
> - C4
> - C5
> - C6
> - C7
> - ...

I want to perform cluster analysis to find out which respondents have similar feelings and what are the most often selected feelings in each cluster. The output is basically a set of binary codes (present vs absent). The categories are asymmetric: In other words, a 0-0 match should not necessarily be considered similar.

From [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116856/hierarchical-or-two-step-cluster-analysis-for-binary-data) incredibly helpful post, I understood, that [hierarchical cluster analysis, using a dice measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55798/what-is-the-optimal-distance-function-for-individuals-when-attributes-are-nomina/55802#55802) should work in my case. However, I also understood that it is not suitable for a large number of samples due to performance issues. (My sample size is 1500.)

Questions:

1. Is my way of thinking correct?
2. Would you still recommend using hierarchical clustering?
3. If no, what else would you recommend?
4. If yes, how bad will the performance be / how long will it take SPSS to run this? (I don't have the dataset yet, so I can't try it out.)

Comment: You seem having partly misunderstood the links. Dice measure suggests itself when you have nominal data such as single-choice question (and so the binary variables from it will be the dummies). In your place, I see a multiple choice question leaving us a set of binary variables. They are of "ordinal" (selected vs not selected) sense. Measures such as Jaccard or Ochiai (cosine) will do.

Comment: You can do hierarchical clustering (for example complete or average linkage): 1500 objects is not too much (SPSS will process it in few seconds). But given that some greedy algos [may become riskyly suboptimal](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3277) with thousands of objects you might consider doing the analysis [on halfs of the sample](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/189012/3277), and compare the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations and remarks! Reading the replies to the other questions again, I see that i probably missed some points. Anyway, I am glad that the analysis should work.