# Does it make sense to run DBSCAN on the output from t-SNE?

Tags: clustering, tsne, dbscan

Performed time series clustering where I used DTW to generate a distance matrix.  The distance matrix was then given as an input to t-SNE where the two-dimensional results from t-SNE were used for clustering with DBSCAN.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

T-SNE is a manifold technique and as such does not preserve distances; therefore it is not recommended to run distance-based (e.g. k-means) or density-based (e.g. DBSCAN) clustering algorithms on the output of T-SNE. This has been [asked before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263539/k-means-clustering-on-the-output-of-t-sne).

If you want a dimensional reduction algorithm that *does* preserve distances, you can use PCA instead of T-SNE. PCA gives you an orthogonal rotation of your original data; one of the properties on an orthogonal transformation is that it preserves distances. When you use PCA for dimensional reduction by projecting into a lower dimensional space by throwing out factors with small eigenvectors, you lose only a small amount of information about distance.

Comment: On time series with differing lengths one cannot use PCA. However, MDS (Multidimensional scaling) will construct a lower dimensional embedding that preserves distances, and that is a good starting point here.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I'd be very interested to hear your opinion about the answer I just posted in the duplicate thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352138/28666.

Comment: I do seem to get distinct clusters from using dbscan on data from tsne. After I did a row-wise normalization of data I seem to get time series clustered on outliers in the time series.