# HDBSCAN: most data clustered as noise (-1)

Tags: clustering, noise, dbscan

I am trying to perform topic modeling on text data, ie. cluster the text messages by topic. I am approaching this by using a BERT model to get sentence embeddings, then use T-sne to reduce the dimensionality of the embeddings to an 8-dimensional space. In the end, I use HDBSCAN to cluster the dimensionally-reduced embeddings.

When i do so, about 40% of the data points in the train set are labelled/clustered as -1 (noise). When predicting on new data, 60% of points get labelled as -1. This is really high fraction because i know most of the data should belong to a topic, and I am also setting the HDBSCAN parameter `min_samples = 1`.

I have seen other people also face such issue with hdbscan. Does this scenario mean that i might be doing something wrong and need to make more adjustments to my data, or such a scenario is typical for hdbscan?
If the latter is true, should i resort to soft-clustering with hdbscan, or try another clustering method completely?

Comment: Although t-SNE reduces the data to two or three dimensions does it diminish the semantic signal from the text too much? The two and three dimensions used by t-SNE are good for graphing, but since you know what phrases are similar (by reading them) maybe graphing is not necessarily of prime concern? Soft-clustering seems a good idea and also HDBSCAN directly, that is without intermediate t-SNE.

Comment: “In conclusions, use t-SNE for visualization (and try different parameters to get something visually pleasing!), but rather do not run clustering afterwards, in particular do not use distance- or density based algorithms, as this information was intentionally (!) lost.”https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263539/clustering-on-the-output-of-t-sne

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: thank you @SingleMalt The issue is that original embeddings are 384 dimensional, so clustering will suffer on such high dimension. I need to reduce the dimensionality before clustering as a result. Do you know of any better approach than t-sne?

Comment: Am unfamiliar with how BERT works. Would try copying whatever has been done in the literature for BERT or similar models. Soft hdbscan could be used as a baseline. With hdbscan, can you reduce minPts and increase Eps to reduce points identified as noise?

Comment: [Bertopic](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic) implements this approach using UMP as a reduction method. However I still have the same issue with getting half of the data labeled as -1.

Answer (score 3):

there are two parameters to set in dbscan, one `minPts`, another is distance `eps` for searching neighbors.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

Make the `eps` larger and make the `minPts` smaller, will solve your problem (most data are not in clusters). What you did is setting the `minPts` to 1, but not setting the `eps`.

Try a larger number on `eps`

Answer (score 2):

HDBSCAN is a density-based clustering algorithm. By using t-SNE, you are inherently losing out on information, since the algorithm preserves neither distances nor density, both of which are essential for HDBSCAN. Since you are interested in preserving the density for HDBSCAN,

Since you need to reduce the dimensionality of your embeddings, you may want to look into using DensMAP or UMAP in place of t-SNE. see [link](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/densmap_demo.html).

Additionally, it could also be of value to try higher values for your min_samples parameter. HDBSCAN will use the min_samples parameter to estimate a probability density function for your data. Using a very low value for min_samples will result in a very noisy estimate for the PDF while using a very high value will result in the finer details of the PDF being lost.

If you'd like to look into it more, consider taking a look at this [article](https://pberba.github.io/stats/2020/01/17/hdbscan/) that offers some insight into the workings of HDBSCAN.

Answer (score 0):

https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/algorithm/algorithm.html

Have you tried clustering after using UMAP? It dimensionally reduces the dataset and will make HDBSCAN perform more effectively. It seems to be quite a popular approach.

Comment: This should be a comment.  It does not seem to be an answer by CV's standards.

Comment: UMAP distorts the data, and really should NOT be used for clustering. The results can be very misleading, see all the criticism of tSNE and UMAP in the bioinformatics domain.