# When is it appropriate to use t-SNE and how can I trust its output to faithfully represent higher dimensional separation?

Tags: python, tsne

Given the discussion on [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/264647/389611) what appropriate assumptions and contingencies would allow tSNE to have an informative interpretation?

It's hard to come away from that answer feeling like I can ever trust results from tSNE to ever show me if higher dimension data has meaningful separation. Are there other methods that do a better job?

Comment: My personal experience is that t-SNE is prone to introducing the impression of separation where separation in fact doesn't exist or is much weaker than it looks like. On the other hand, t-SNE can occasionally reveal separation in high-dimensional space that is otherwise hard to find. One thing you could do is to look at the original distances within and between "clusters" that you see in a t-SNE plot to see to what extent the view is distorted.