# How to check whether there are any clusters in data?

Tags: correlation, clustering, k-means, validation

In short: I am using **k-means** clustering with **correlation distance**. How to check, how many clusters should be used, **if any**?

There are many indices and answers on *how to establish a number of clusters* when grouping data:
[example 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11691/how-to-tell-if-data-is-clustered-enough-for-clustering-algorithms-to-produce-m), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376462/3067956), etc. For now, I am using [Dunn's index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunn_index), but it is not sufficient due to one of the reasons described below.

All those approaches exhibit at least one of following problems, I have to avoid:

Indexes:

- clustering quality index derivation makes some assumptions regarding data covariance matrix, i.e. since such moment only euclidean or euclidean-like metrics apply - correlation one is not an option anymore
- it requires at least two nonempty clusters to compare already calculated partitions - there is no possibility to state whether there is any reason to make a division into groups at all

Clustering approaches:

- clustering approaches estimating number of clusters itself (e.g. affinity propagation) are much slower and do not scale well

To sum up: is there any criterion or index, which allows to check for **existence** of groups in data (maybe estimating number of them), without limitation on metric used?

EDIT: Space I am operating on has up to few thousands features.

Comment: You may want to look at [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) instead of k-means, which automatically determines the number of clusters - potentially just one.

Comment: @StephanKolassa in high dimensionality DBSCAN enters O(n^2) what scales poorly. I am operating on a space with up to few thousands features.

Comment: There isn't anything below O(n²). K-means has worst case even worse than O(n²) if I recall correctly. And if I'm not mistaken, Dunn's index is O(n²) too (Silhouette definitely is).

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, it depends on how it's calculated. Dunn's index can be calculated differently, depending on the definition of inter- and intracluster distances, there are some options (something like 18 variations). I use those with O(n) complexity - they work pretty well, but none will ever provide 1-cluster case.
For k-means itself, Lloyd's algorithm reaches O(nkdi) where n is number of observations, k - number of clusters, d - dimensionality, i - number of iterations.

Comment: k-means: the problem is that the number of iterations, i, is exponential in n, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Complexity look for "superpolynomial". So worse than O(n³). P.S. k-means should *only* be used with Bregman divergences, such as squared Euclidean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323784/absolute-pearson-correlation-distance-in-kmeans-matlab

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, thanks for your explanation. In my application, it suffices to keep maximal number of iterations limited. That's why I did not connect it above with n.
Isn't the problem with correlation distance resolved by proper data transformation? I.e. normalization of all observations to have mean 0 and norm 1?
Also, data is specific in such a way, that no negative correlation is found (case you shown - with zero mean - does not occur).

Comment: Then pearson correlation is cosine, and spherical k-means should be okay to use, yes. I don't know if the results are actually meaningful. What are the least squares you minimize, does this optimize your problem?