# Which methods can help us to understand clustering model is good or bad?

Tags: clustering, k-means, accuracy, unsupervised-learning, topological-data-analysis

In some clustering algorithm, ex: `K-Means` cluster, it is very sensitive with outliers, so we need to remove outliers before aplly `K-Means`, or it will be bad clustering. So :

1. How can we know some points are outliers if we can not plot it ( high dimension data ) ?
2. how can we know its `K-Means` model is good or bad ? Because it is unsupervised learning, so we can not calculate accuracy rate ( something likes F1 score ,... ). Or do we have any method to know an unsupervised learning model is good or bad ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **checking the loss (sum of distance in k-means setting) on testing data set**.

In unsupervised learning, we also need both training and testing data set. Because it is also common to have over-fitting in unsupervised setting. For example, in K-means if we increase number of clusters $k$, the clustering performance (loss function / sum of distance) will always get better in the training data, and eventually will over-fit the data. The extreme example, would be make every data point as a cluster center, then loss is $0$.

To evaluate how good is the clustering algorithm, one valid approach is testing if the model (number of clusters and centers) is still good on a held out testing data.

---

I was talking about unsupervised learning in general (including probablistic model, mixture of Gaussian etc.), for K-means specifically, you can find answer here (if not duplicate).

[How to tell if data is "clustered" enough for clustering algorithms to produce meaningful results?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11691/how-to-tell-if-data-is-clustered-enough-for-clustering-algorithms-to-produce-m)

Comment: Why won't increasing k lower the loss value on a test set?

Comment: @eric_kernfeld think about the extreme example, when we put a cluster center in every data point in training. The testing data should have different data points. In such a case, training loss is 0, but testing is definitely not, unless two data sets identical.

Comment: What you say is true, but not exactly what I am getting at. Suppose you have training and test sets of size 200 and you increase the number of centers from 8 to 16. Don't you think the test set loss will decrease?

Comment: Also, how do you use this tactic to compare methods? Two methods may have completely different loss functions, or the loss functions may be arbitrarily scaled.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld comparing between different models is another question and not what OP original asked.

Comment: Depends on error on train set and test set, how can i know it is good or bad ? We will compare error on train set and test set with same number of cluster, or we will compare error on train set and test set between variant numbers of cluster ?